# Alternative of Firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

Firebug is blocked at work, so can anybody suggest an alternative of it?

Answer (score 3):

FireBug 1.9.0 is block, but the newest version 1.9.1 is working: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug

Comment: Indeed.  The blocked version has an exploitable security bug, hence the mandatory update.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox now has a built-in tools which embrace-and-extend Firebug. The built-in Script Panel can be activated using the following keyboard shortcut:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + s</kbd>
- OS X: <kbd>command + shift + s</kbd>

Here are shortcuts to the other Firebug equivalents:

**Net Panel:**

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + k</kbd>
- OS X: <kbd>command + shift + k</kbd>

**Console Panel***

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + k</kbd>
- OS X: <kbd>command + shift + k</kbd>

*The console is located under the Net content

**HTML Panel:**

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + i</kbd>
- OS X: <kbd>command + shift + i</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome and Internet Explorer both have similar functionality built-in to them. You can access these features by pressing `F12`. I use these as an alternative to Firebug occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mozilla own debugger. Though it is not as advance as firebug. It comes with FF 10+

Answer (score 1):

How about firebug lite? No installation needed (I've only used for IE though..)

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite